# Three routers, one switch

Tags: networking, router, switch, fiber

I have a problem. The broadband ISP in my area is really unreliable, so I have decided to get an "Airfiber" subscription along with the one I have. The idea is to connect both routers' LAN ports to a single network switch, to which I will connect all the non-WiFi Deskop computers. I hope that this will allow the network to access the internet from both routers parallely, and allow all the computers to the still access the internet when any one router does not work. I want to know (in simple words) what extra configuration needs to be done for this to work.

The second part is that both these routers combined do not have enough of a device limit to satisfy the large number of Wi-Fi devices such as laptops and smartphones on the network. So if I connect the WAN port of yet another router (in WAP mode) to the swich from earlier, will it also use the other routers to access the internet and swich over whenever either one fails? Also I wish to know what extra configuration will be required here. I am a little concerned about IP addresses because all 3 routers are set to use 192.168 based IP addresses by default.

I am still a novice when it comes to networking, so it would be quite appreciated if you answer in simple words and guide me to youtube tutorials. :)

Comment: Your proposed solution won't work. You need some kind of router that can perform failover.

Comment: your clients need a single unambiguous router IP to send traffic destined for the internet to (eg the default gateway). the router indicated by the default gateway will always receive packets for the Internet, and since the router they point to dictates which ISP is used, the routers will not be used in parallel, load-balanced, or dynamic to account for one ISP or the other being down. as others have mentioned, a dual-wan router is the simplest solution. then the clients can always point to the routers lan IP, and the router itself handles all the decisions on what ISP it goes out.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem depends on the routers you have, the size of your computer network, the requirements for this network, and security. It is not trivial task, there are some pitfalls, but **it is possible**. For general idea take a look at this (quite old now) question regarding pfSense routers: https://serverfault.com/questions/604631/how-do-i-configure-a-second-pfsense-server-for-failover

You ask for YouTube tutorial, so for example - [High Availability with 2 pfSense](https://youtu.be/U-cTRf5uUEY?si=Xdl2QbnDCJ4ehHNo).

pfSense is BSD-based and, as I can remember, it uses **CARP** protocol for failover (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol). Some/most routers use **VRRP** (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol). For example you can configure VRRP on Mikrotik routers - [MikroTik - Configuring VRRP](https://youtu.be/sgXi2jJv48I?si=kLCNDqtXllBRWwC_). If you search 'vrrp' on youtube you will find a bunch of videos.

Regarding IP subnet 192.168.x.x/?? (/24?) - if you need VRRP-like solution, your routers have to be on the same subnet with "one leg" each - they have to share "common", "floating" gateway address for your hosts (and your hosts also have to be on that subnet).

If you need more help, please provide more information - what kind of routers you have, what is the size of your computer network (how many hosts are there), what kind of addressing do you have, is there one subnet or many subnets, do you have a separate dhcp server that assigns addresses in your network, or do you want a router to do it, etc.

Comment: Please use correct markdown for weblinks - please see the formatting bar or the `?` button to the far right of the formatting bar

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how it'd work - a *router* links two or more subnets, and plugging in multiple consumer routers to a switch wouldn't work, because a switch isn't aware where the packets should go, and the clients would see 2 DHCP servers and such on the same interface and be very confused.

The simplest option here is just to run two seperate networks, and let the systems in question failover if one goes down - either with 2 seperate wireless networks, both of which your clients are set up to connect to, or two hardwared networks, or one of each. Most devices should failover if a link is down, and there's an alternate available, and will default to the best link available based on the metric.

If you don't want to configure each client seperately, then *broadly* you need *one* multihomed or load balancing router that'd support and be connected to your three two wan links. Also 192.168.X.Y can be *one* subnet, and there's nothing stopping you from running 192.168.1.x, 192.168.2.x and such. You may also find load balancing devices that'd do this too.

Quite a few consumer or prosumer routers *do* support dual-wan out of the box, and while that router is a single point of failure, its generally simple to configure on a consumer router, and is advertised as a feature so its easy to find. Its the easiest way to get what you need *running*. You might want to go something that's enterprise grade if you have a large number of users.

> The second part is that both these routers combined do not have enough of a device limit to satisfy the large number of Wi-Fi devices such as laptops and smartphones on the network.

This leads to a few questions like "do you really need to run more than 253 devices at once?" If you do - there's a broader set of issues than just needing to load balance, and chances are you've somewhat outgrown consumer gear. You'd need to support a *significant* number of connections to the router (and size it appropriately) and managing the network becomes a lot more complicated than a novice networking person can handle.

In theory, you *could* run your routers *behind* the dual wan router with different subnets in a sort of double NAT setup *but* practically that many users would bog down most consumer wireless routers (or even prosumer ones) before you ran out of IPs.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to connect both routers' LAN ports to a single network switch, to which I will connect all the non-WiFi Deskop computers. I hope that this will allow the network to access the internet from both routers parallely, and allow all the computers to the still access the internet when any one router does not work. I want to know (in simple words) what extra configuration needs to be done for this to work.

It probably will not work. You could try to do this, making sure that each router has (at the very minimum) a different IP address, but Internet access doesn't "merge" like a liquid – each device will latch onto *one* router (whichever is the first to make a DHCP offer) and will continue to use only that router whether it has Internet connectivity or not. Even if the bad router is powered off, the devices will not automatically switch over to another until e.g. they're physically re-connected or their DHCP lease expires.

It would be more easily doable if all three routers supported e.g. VRRP or CARP or another similar "virtual IP" mechanism; but I'm 90% sure your routers don't have that. (Other than Mikrotik and pfSense/OpnSense, it's usually considered an "enterprise" feature.)

The easiest way would be to connect all clients through a single router that has 3 different uplinks and some functionality to periodically check which uplink is usable. There are apparently "Multi-WAN" or "Dual-WAN" routers that have this function built-in. (I remember pfSense used to have dpinger for that purpose.)

> The second part is that both these routers combined do not have enough of a device limit to satisfy the large number of Wi-Fi devices such as laptops and smartphones on the network. So if I connect the WAN port of yet another router (in WAP mode) to the swich from earlier, will it also use the other routers to access the internet and swich over whenever either one fails?

An access point (or a router in WAP mode) will not do *any* Internet access by itself – it will function almost exactly like a switch, only wireless. Each device on Wi-Fi will independently do DHCP and pick up the 'gateway' IP address.

With a network your size, you should probably be getting dedicated Wi-Fi access points rather than routers.

> I am a little concerned about IP addresses because all 3 routers are set to use 192.168 based IP addresses by default.

By default they do not use the entire 192.168.x.x/16 range – usually you'll see them configured to use a /24 range, which is 1/256'th of that. For example, if one router uses 192.168.2.0/24 and another uses 192.168.3.0/24, they do not overlap even though both are "192.168" addresses.

From your description, it sounds like /24 (with space for ~250 addresses) might be a little too small, but there's still plenty of space in the 192.168.0.0/16 to divide it up into e.g. /20's (~4000 addresses each) without having them overlap.

> I am still a novice when it comes to networking, so it would be quite appreciated if you answer in simple words and guide me to youtube tutorials.

The "three routers" part isn't really something that can be a single video tutorial, as it pretty much starts with "you will need a more capable router" (whether you buy it or build one from a Linux PC).